# Parallel.ForEach on List<Object> Thread Safety

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

As far as Thread Safety goes is this ok to do or do I need to be using a different collection ?

```
        List<FileMemberEntity> fileInfo = getList(); 

        Parallel.ForEach(fileInfo, fileMember =>
        {
              //Modify each fileMember 
        }
```

Comment: Please keep questions singular.

Comment: are you modifying anything in your foreach loop? if not, then there's probably no concern for thread safety. If you are modifying, then you'll need to perform a lock

Comment: can I use a different collection and not need a lock

Comment: You don't have to lock the `List<T>` as long as you are not modifying the list.

Comment: without knowing what you're doing in your loop, i can only make arbitrary guesses

Comment: Sorry  I updated my code ... I am modifying the collection inside the loop

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As long as you are only modifying the contents of the item that is passed to the method, there is no locking needed.

(Provided of course that there are no duplicate reference in the list, i.e. two references to the same `FileMemberEntity` instance.)

If you need to modify the list itself, create a copy that you can iterate, and use a lock when you modify the list:

```
List<FileMemberEntity> fileInfo = getList();

List<FileMemberEntity> copy = new List<FileMemberEntity>(fileInfo);
object sync = new Object();

Parallel.ForEach(copy, fileMember => {
  // do something
  lock (sync) {
    // here you can add or remove items from the fileInfo list
  }
  // do something
});
```

Comment: The contents being the collection .... not what is contained in the collection correct ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: The contents being whatever is in the `FileMemberEntity` instance that is passed as `fileMember` to the method.

Comment: So will that make all the other threads stop until its out of the lock or with the Parallel.ForEach will the thread go on to another item in the list ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: The lock will only protect the code inside the lock from being executed by more than one thread at the time. The code outside the lock itself can still run in several threads at the same time.

Comment: doesn't this defeat the purpose of parallelism? in this case wouldn't make more sense to use the standard foreach?

Comment: @HosseinAarabi It does defeat the purpose.  Good story about this here https://softwarekeith.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/quickly-detect-performance-bottlenecks-in-multithreaded-net-applications-by-measuring-and-analyzing-processor-queue-length-and-thread-contention-performance-counte/

Comment: @HosseinAarabi: As this is working with files, the part of the code outside the lock is supposedly taking substantially longer than the code inside the lock. If that is not the case, then your assumption is correct.

Comment: What if you do something like "fileMember = new FileMemberEntity(...);"?

Answer (score 10):

You're safe since you are just reading. Just don't modify the list while you are iterating over its items.

Comment: I am modifying the items in the collection

Comment: That's fine, as long as you're not modifying the actual collection itself. You can't reorder items in it, nor can you add or remove items to it.

Comment: So if I am updating the items in the list it doesn't matter as long last I don't change the actual collection ?

Answer (score 3):

We should use less lock object to make it faster. Only lock object in different local threads of Parrallel.ForEach:

```
List<FileMemberEntity> copy = new List<FileMemberEntity>(fileInfo);
object sync = new Object();

Parallel.ForEach<FileMemberEntity, List<FileMemberEntity>>(
      copy,
      () => { return new List<FileMemberEntity>(); },
      (itemInCopy, state, localList) =>
      {
         // here you can add or remove items from the fileInfo list
         localList.Add(itemInCopy);
         return localList;
      },
      (finalResult) => { lock (sync) copy.AddRange(finalResult); }
); 

 // do something
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff963547.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If it does not matter what order the `FileMemberEntity` objects are acted on, you can use `List<T>` because you are not modifying the list.

If you must ensure some sort of ordering, you can use `OrderablePartitioner<T>` as a base class and implement an appropriate partitioning scheme.  For example, if the `FileMemberEntity` has some sort of categorization and you must process each of the categories in some specific order, you would want to go this route.

Hypothetically if you have

> Object 1 Category A
>
> Object 2 Category A
>
> Object 3 Category B

there is no guarantee that `Object 2 Category A` will be processed before `Object 3 Category B` is processed when iterating a `List<T>` using `Parallel.ForEach`.

The MSDN documentation you link to provides an example of how to do that.

Comment: I am modifying the collection inside the foreach

Comment: If you are modifying the objects in the collection (rather than the collection itself) that is just fine.