# Parallel.Foreach in dynamic List

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks

I am working on the file uploading to server.I am using Parallel.Foreach to split the task.In my Sample Source

```
Task.Factory.StartNew (delegate 
{        
    Parallel.ForEach (metaDatas, new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 },          itemModel => 
    {
        apimanager.ContentConnector.uploadItem (0, itemModel.PhysicalFileName, itemModel.ParentId, itemModel.Size, itemModel.path, fetchDataDelegate, finishedUploadingDataDelegate, failedToUploadDataDelegate);                           
    });
    Console.WriteLine ("Upload Completed");
});
```

in my case metaDatas list is dynamically update.how can i use the latest metaDatas List in Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232167/parallel-foreach-on-listobject-thread-safety

Comment: Are you using IO requests to upload your data, via `HTTP` requests or `FTP`?

Comment: metaDas should be a ConcurrentQueue or a BlockingCollection. A `List<>` is the wrong choice here.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem.
I found a non standard solution that can help.

```
var buffer = new BlockingCollection<Task>(maxThreads);

// process while download all threads
while (!Queue.IsEmpty || buffer.Count > 0)
{
    SomeClass item;
    while (Queue.TryDequeue(out item))
    {
        var localItem = item;

        var localTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            // work with your item
            // in this place you can append Queue    

            buffer.Take(); // free buffer for adding new threads
        });

        buffer.Add(localTask);
        localTask.Start();
    }

    // in this point Queue is empty,
    // but buffer have remaining thread
    Task.Delay(50).Wait();
}
```

So, Queue is `ConcurrentQueue<SomeClass>`, your dymanic source

It's not perfect solution, but it's work.