# Modifying elements of IEnumerable<T> inside a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am modifying a list of elements inside a parallel foreach like for example:

```
    var items = ...; // array to process
    for(;;){
            Parallel.ForEach(items, po, (it) =>
            {
                    it.Date = DateTime.Now; // Modify it with some logic.
            }
    }
```

My case does not involve any racing conditions and this similar question is not much relevant to my case (since I am not interested about thread safety):

[Parallel.ForEach on List<Object> Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232167/parallel-foreach-on-listobject-thread-safety)

The `Date` in the above code is of type `DateTime?` and is initially `null`. I never turn it into `null` in my code, I only set it to `DateTime.Now`.
The problem is that it seems like the `Parallel.ForEach` serves copies of the `items` and not the real instances, making the update of them impossible. I understood this because I got `null` values of `Date` for items that were previously set.

Is this expected behavior? I can't find any documentation for this although it sounds a bit logical to make copies of the data before feeding it to the threads.

I ask, because in the question-link posted above, no-one said anything about this (updating the objects inside the parallel foreach) not being possible/reliable.

Is there any good-looking code as a workaround for this problem (so that I can update the items while looping the array)?

**UPDATE:**

In my case `T` is something like this:

```
public class GroupSettings
    {
        public GroupSettings(int groupId, string email)
        {
            GroupId = groupId;
            Email = email;
        }
        public int GroupId { get; protected set; }
        public string Email { get; protected set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

I have even tried putting `Date` inside an inner class (just in case the object reference was the same in the copies), but with no change in behavior.

Comment: What's the `T` in this case? Sounds like it's probably a mutable struct... if not, please post a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Of what type are your `items`?  Is it a value type or a reference type?  Your code should work if it's a reference type (class) but not for a value type (struct).

Comment: I have updated the question above, regarding the type of `T`. :)

Comment: Why is your `Parallel.ForEach` inside of an infinite loop (`for(;;)`)?

Comment: @juharr I run it inside a Windows service and I break it from inside the loops only when the service should stop.

Comment: Can you show how you initially populate `items`?  Is it created from a Linq query by any chance?  If it is the issue might be lazy evaluation thus every time you iterate `items` the values will be re-evaluated based on the query.

Comment: @NathanC I think the parenthesis offers anything. I doubt something will change by removing it.

Comment: I've made a demo to try and reproduce this. The result: I couldn't. So, I will investigate the code I have a bit more. I have the impression that somebody goes and refreshes the whole array every once in a while in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found what was wrong here.
There was another part of the code that was refreshing that array of objects and not copying the old `Date` properties to the new objects.

It is good for me to know that `Parallel.ForEach` can update the items reliably and that it was our code's fault for the issue. :)
I just hope I haven't wasted anybody else's time.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your items are IEnumerable, there can be a situation as follows:

```
    private void Test()
    {

        var items = GetListItems(); 
        var po = new ParallelOptions();

        for (; ; )
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(items, po, (it) =>
                {
                    it.Date = DateTime.Now; // Add breakpoint here.
                });

                var testList = items.ToList();
            }
    }

    private IEnumerable<GroupSettings> GetListItems()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                yield return new GroupSettings(new Random().Next(), Guid.NewGuid() + "@gmail.com") { Date = DateTime.Now };
            }
    }
```

In this case there is no a list of items, just enumerator. So every time you enumerate(i.e., use foreach, .ToList etc, call GetEnumerator() to put it simple) you get a new set of objects. 
So it's better to cast IEnumerable to list(.ToList()), then proceed.

ps Though it can cause other problems