# Improve performance of getting distinct items

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert below code to LINQ. Lists can sometimes contains 20k or 30k items. So I'm looking for something that improves performance and runs faster. Below is my code:

```
     if(list1 != null)
     {
       foreach (var item in list1)
       {
        if(!list2.Any( x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Number == item.Number))
        {
          list2.Add(item)
        }
       }
     }
```

I tried using Parallel.ForEach but it throws a "Collection was modified" error.

Comment: What does `list2` start off with? Is it empty?

Comment: @JonSkeet - it might have values or it might be empty. I have both cases in my requirement. So solution must be able to handle both

Comment: Are either `list` variables results from an Entity Framework call?

Comment: @krillgar - i'm a beginner learning c# and linq. Sorry I did not get your question. Can you elaborate

Comment: It would be better to use a Dictionary<string,int> or Dictionary<string,List<int>> depending if the name is unique..  The key in a dictionary is a hash which will speed up searches.  Using a List to find items means searching all N items, the hash is a tree with execution log<2>(N).

Comment: You might want to consider making `list2` a `HashSet` with a custom `IEqualityComparer` that will compare your items on `Name` and `Number`.  Then you can just loop through and `Add` items without having to do the increasingly expensive lookup.  This will only add the first "unique" item.

Comment: @jdweng Actually a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, T>` where `T` is the type of `item` would be more appropriate.

Comment: If you are asking how to .Add to *one* List in Parallel.ForEach, you can't do it without some modifications. [Parallel.ForEach on List<Object> Thread Safety](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27147361/1115360). *However*, I am slightly surprised that your code as shown takes any noticeable amount of time.

Comment: @user Are your two collections you're working with coming from a Database, or are they hard-coded `List<T>` variables? If they come from a database, you will experience a different cause for lag than you do if they are simply in-memory.

Comment: @krillgar - no they do not come from database. For about 21k items my above code takes 5 seconds. I want it to be faster.

Comment: @juharr- can you please give me a sample that supports you explanation.I'm new to c# and really not sure how to implement your solution. Would be great if you could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you reading this data from a file?  21k records in memory should be sub second for a modern computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the LINQ [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) method. It needs an IEqualityComparer set up, but luckily the MSDN example has just what you need already written:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random rand = new Random();

        // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct for Distinct()
        public class Product
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
        }

        // Custom comparer for the Product class
        class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
        {
            // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
            public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
            {

                //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

                //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                    return false;

                //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
                return x.Number == y.Number && x.Name == y.Name;
            }

            // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
            // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

            public int GetHashCode(Product product)
            {
                //Check whether the object is null
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

                //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
                int hashProductName = product.Name == null ? 0 : product.Name.GetHashCode();

                //Get hash code for the Code field.
                int hashProductCode = product.Number.GetHashCode();

                //Calculate the hash code for the product.
                return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
            }

        }

        static string RandomLetter()
        {
            return (rand.Next((int)'A', (int)'Z' + 1)).ToString();
        }

        static List<Product> CreateTestData()
        {
            int nItems = 20000;
            List<Product> data = new List<Product>(nItems);
            for (int i = 1; i <= nItems; i++)
            {
                data.Add(new Product { Name = RandomLetter() + RandomLetter(), Number = i % 10 });
            }

            return data;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = CreateTestData();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            List<Product> noduplicates = list1.Distinct(new ProductComparer()).ToList();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"x items: {list1.Count()} no duplicates: {noduplicates.Count()} Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            List<Product> list2 = new List<Product>();
            if (list1 != null)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                foreach (var item in list1)
                {
                    if (!list2.Any(x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Number == item.Number))
                    {
                        list2.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"x items: {list1.Count()} list2: {noduplicates.Count()} Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
x items: 20000 no duplicates: 6393 Time: 12 ms
x items: 20000 list2: 6393 Time: 4225 ms
```

If you already had some data, you could use the [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union) method instead, again using the comparer.

N.B. My `RandomLetter()` function does not do what I intended. But it suffices.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

20 - 30k items are not so much. All you need is to replace the potentially slow linear search

```
list2.Any(x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Number == item.Number)
```

with fast lookup data structure.

The easiest is to build a `HashSet` with anonymous type containing the `Name` and `Number` properties. In order to do that, you can use the following handy custom extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
    }
}
```

and the code in question would be like this:

```
if (list1 != null)
{
    var keys = list2.Select(item => new { item.Name, item.Number }).ToHashSet();
    foreach (var item in list1)
    {
        var key = new { item.Name, item.Number };
        if (!keys.Contains(key))
        {
            list2.Add(item);
            keys.Add(key);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not LINQ, but it doesn't need to be, since LINQ is for querying, while your code is for modification.

Comment: That's nice and short compared to setting up an IEqualityComparer to use Distinct, and only takes the extra time to set up the HashSet as compared to using Distinct (i.e. it is not much slower than using Distinct). *However*, my test data may not be good enough for a proper comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the sample and thanks for taking time to help me out!!

Comment: Upvoted yours and Andrew's answers, but prefer this for a simple explanation, since OP is `new to c#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make list2 a ConcurrentBag type and do like this. im not 100% sure that it will work as intended though.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
public void test()
{
    var list1 = new List<Item>(); // add items to list1 or maybe load from a database?

    var list2 = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();

    Parallel.ForEach(list1.ToList(), (item, state, arg3) =>
    {
        if (!list2.Any(x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Number == item.Number))
        {
            list2.Add(item);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method takes about twice as long as the OP's method, and does not seem to get the correct result (with my test data) - it doesn't eliminate all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Group by your distiction and select the first record from the group and create your list.

*Fastest if you don't need to provide existing values*

```
var list2 = list1.GroupBy(i => new { i.Name, i.Number })
                 .Select(g=>g.First())
                 .ToList();
```

*Simple if you have existing values (4 times slower than the next version)*

if you `list2` has preexisting values you can do something like this...

```
var keys = list2.ToList();
var toadd = list1.GroupBy(i => new { i.Name, i.Number })
                 .Where(g => !keys.Any(i => i.Name == g.Key.Name
                                         && i.Number == g.Key.Number))
                 .Select(g=>g.First());
list2.AddRange(toadd);
```

*Fastest if you need to update a set with existing values*

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(items);
}

var keys = list2.Select(i => new { i.Name, i.Number }).ToHashSet();
var toadd = list1.GroupBy(i => new { i.Name, i.Number })
                 .Where(g => !keys.Contains(g.Key))
                 .Select(g => g.First());
list2.AddRange(toadd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently optimized Distinct call on list of immutable items which has the same types used as key - a string and an integer. I overloaded object.GetHashCode and precomputed hash code and stored into private field durcing construction. GetHashCode overload just returned value from this private member.

This modification made Distinct call maybe few hundread times faster because internally Distinct iterator uses its internal HashSet implementation that does lot of calls to GetHashCode.

Note: if you overload GetHashCode, you'll need to overload object.Equals too so that Distinct internal iterator uses it.

Remember that you cannot use this kind of hash code caching if your members can change during item object lifetime or you'll need to update cached hash code value each time any of fields used as key (i.e. used in Equals) changes.