# C# Generic List<T> update items

Tags: c#, generic-list

I'm using a `List<T>` and I need to update the objects properties that the list has.

What would be the most **efficient/faster** way to do this? I know that scanning through the index of a `List<T>` would be slower as this list grows and that the `List<T>` is not the most efficient collection to do updates.

That sad, would be better to:

- Remove the match object then add a new one?
- Scan through the list indexes until you find the matching object and then update the object's properties?
- If I have a collection, let's IEnumerable and I want to update that IEnumerable into the List, what would be best approach.

**Stub code sample:**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRepository
{
    List<Product> product = Product.GetProduct();
    public void UpdateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> updatedProduct)
    {
    }
    public void UpdateProduct(Product updatedProduct)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you mean by "update items" here, *can* you simply replace the existing product object with the new one? Either way, if you have no direct access to the existing objects based on whatever it is that is making them a match, then the linear performance of the list is going to be an issue either way. What exactly makes one produce object match another? ProductId? Why then are you not using a dictionary?

Comment: "most efficient/faster way to do this?" isn´t as clear as you think, because it depends on your context. How many objects live in your list? How often do you add/remove items? How often do you access an item? Having said this just chose what works for you and think about performance if you encounter some heavy lags.

Comment: Since you have an Id for each product, you shoudl use a Dictionary to increase performance. Dictionary<int, Product> where the key is ProductId

Comment: I would not remove the existing object and add the new one, if you end up keeping the list and want to replace the object, I would instead overwrite the element at the found index with the new object instead, this is faster because the list does not have to move around other items because of the delete.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, this is about using List<T> and not other Collections. Lets say that the LIST has millions of objects, how to perform dozens or even hundreds of updates a minute to existing items in that list fastest as you can using 1 thread for the Job?

Comment: The List is constantly being updated with new "Products", no issues adding new products. Updating existing Products in the List<> requires 2 things, 1- searching by index of the product (there's no Product.Id to match, but we already have an extension that performs the matching of the Product to update). 2 - Update the Product (here what we found is that coping property by property to the Product to update on the List<Products> is slow process), so using a List<> like this one can we update the complete object in 1 operation instead of mapping all properties and then save them to list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your use case is updating a `List<T>`, which can contains millions of records, and updated records can be a sub-list or just a single record

Following is the Schema:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

> Does `Product` contains a primary key, which means every `Product` object can be uniquely identified and there are no duplicates and every update target a single unique record?

If **Yes**, then it is best to arrange the `List<T>` in the form of `Dictionary<int,T>`, which would mean for an `IEnumerable<T>` every update would be an `O(1)` time complexity and that would mean all the updates could be done depending on the size of the `IEnumerable<T>`, which i don't expect to be very big and though there would be extra memory allocation of different data structure required, but would be a very fast solution.@JamieLupton has already provided a solution on similar lines

> In case `Product` is repeated, there's no primary key, then above solution is not valid, then ideal way to scan through the `List<T>` is Binary Search, whose time complexity is `O(logN)`

Now since size of `IEnumerable<T>` is comparatively small say M, so the overall time complexity would be `O(M*logN)`, where M is much smaller than N and can be neglected.

`List<T>` support Binary Search API, which provides the element index, which can then be used to update the object at relevant index, check [example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/binarysearch) here

> Best Option as per me for such a high number of records would be parallel processing along with binary search

Now since, thread safety is an issue, what I normally do is divide a `List<T>` into `List<T>[]`, since then each unit can be assigned to a separate thread, a simple way is use `MoreLinq` batch Api, where you can fetch the number of system processors as using `Environment.ProcessorCount` and then create `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` as follows:

```
var enumerableList = List<T>.Batch(Environment.ProcessorCount).ToList();
```

Another way is following custom code:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    // data - List<T>
    // dataCount - Calculate once and pass to avoid accessing the property everytime
    // Size of Partition, which can be function of number of processors
    public static List<T>[] SplitList<T>(this List<T> data, int dataCount, int partitionSize)
    {
        int remainderData;    
        var fullPartition = Math.DivRem(dataCount, partitionSize, out remainderData);    
        var listArray = new List<T>[fullPartition];    
        var beginIndex = 0;

        for (var partitionCounter = 0; partitionCounter < fullPartition; partitionCounter++)
        {
            if (partitionCounter == fullPartition - 1)
                listArray[partitionCounter] = data.GetRange(beginIndex, partitionSize + remainderData);
            else
                listArray[partitionCounter] = data.GetRange(beginIndex, partitionSize);    
            beginIndex += partitionSize;
        }    
        return listArray;
    }
}
```

Now you can create `Task[]`, where each `Task` is assigned for every element `List<T>`, on the `List<T>[]` generated above, then Binary search for each sub partition. Though its repetitive but would be using the power of Parallel processing and Binary search. Each `Task` can be started and then we can wait using `Task.WaitAll(taskArray)` to wait for Task processing to finish

Over and above that, if you want to create a `Dictionary<int,T>[]` and thus use parallel processing then this would be fastest.

Final integration of `List<T>[]` to `List<T>` can be done using Linq `Aggregation` or `SelectMany` as follows:

```
List<T>[] splitListArray = Fetch splitListArray;

// Process  splitListArray

var finalList = splitListArray.SelectMany(obj => obj).ToList()
```

> Another option would be to use `Parallel.ForEach` along with a thread safe data structure like `ConcurrentBag<T>` or may be `ConcurrentDictionary<int,T>` in case you are replacing complete object, but if its property update then a simple `List<T>` would work. `Parallel.ForEach` internally use range partitioner similar to what I have suggested above

**Solutions mentioned above ideally depends on your use case, you shall be able to use combination to achieve the best possible result. Let me know, in case you need specific example**

Comment: thanks for your answer, we can't use Dictionaries, the List<T> is not sorted, Binary search won't do the Job

Comment: Why dictionaries can't be used, is it due to data duplication, multiple records per key. I can understand binary search issue, but range partitioning is always feasible, which can be used for parallel processing

Comment: Let me know if you need any help, especially related to the creation of range partition and Task parallelism

Comment: thanks, we had good results with this solution, almost done... thank you for your input very helpful.

Comment: Glad it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using Dictionary instead of List if you want fast lookups. In your case it would be the product Id (which I am assuming is unique). [Dictionary MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For example:

```
public class ProductRepository
    {
        Dictionary<int, Product> products = Product.GetProduct();
        public void UpdateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> updatedProducts)
        {
            foreach(var productToUpdate in updatedProducts)
            {
                UpdateProduct(productToUpdate);
            }

            ///update code here...
        }
        public void UpdateProduct(Product productToUpdate)
        {
            // get the product with ID 1234 
            if(products.ContainsKey(productToUpdate.ProductId))
            {
                var product = products[productToUpdate.ProductId];
                ///update code here...
                product.ProductName = productToUpdate.ProductName;
            }
            else
            {
                //add code or throw exception if you want here.
                products.Add(productToUpdate.ProductId, productToUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the `Update` is replacement and the `Id` in the Dictionary key doesn't remain same, OP doesn't suggest that that only non Key attributes would change

Comment: I've updated the UpdateProduct code above. This approach will only work if you have a unique Key that doesn't change. If ProductID changes then you could use 'ID' i.e. Primary Key from Database or something similar.

Comment: This would be a good option for a specific use case +1, though ideally for millions of records I would prefer to combine it with power of Parallel processing

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we can't use Dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is efficiency?

Unless there are literally thousands of items doing a foreach, or for or any other type of looping operation will most likely only show differences in the milleseconds. Really? Hence you have wasted more time (in costs of a programmer at $XX per hour than an end user costs) trying to find that *best*.

So if you have literally thousands of records I would recommend that efficiency be found by parallel processing the list with the [Parallel.Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2) method which can process more records to save time with the overhead of threading.

---

IMHO if the record count is greater than 100 it implies that there is a database being used. If a database is involved, write an update sproc and call it a day; I would be hard pressed to write a one-off program to do *a specific update* which could be done in an easier fashion in said database.

Comment: For Parallel processing first thing required is Concurrent collection, which would change the underlying data structure itself, closest being `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj That's not correct, `Parallel.ForEach` does not automatically force you to use a concurrent collection. He only wants to access/update properties of list items, not manipulating the collection itself.

Comment: @PeterWurzinger that's only when you are not updating just reading, here you are modifying the original collection, therefore thread safety is required

Comment: He is not modifying the collection but the properties of contained items. When going with `List<T>`, that's fine.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/oHNNYt

EDIT: See this SO-answer for a complete explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232167/parallel-foreach-on-listobject-thread-safety

Comment: That's your assumption, OP has not clearly indicated, in-fact OP suggest **Remove the match object then add a new one** and in fact the link that you have posted also use a `lock`, when complete object is modified / replaced. Most common way that people do is replacing one object by another, not just the property update, which is desirable but could be little tedious and can lead to logical mistakes. Otherwise `Parallel.ForEach` also works using range partitioner, which I have too suggested in my answer

Comment: "I need to update the objects properties" is what he wants to achieve, and "Remove the match object then add a new one" is a possible option he wants to discuss in terms of efficiency. I don't see any intention or need to modify the collection itself, so using `Parallel.ForEach` on a plain `List<T>` without a concurrency wrapper appears to be a legit approach to me.

EDIT: Using `Parallel.ForEach` implies potentially using multiple threads, which most likely contradicts the restriction of only using 1 thread (as stated in a comment).

Comment: That's correct Peter Wurzinger. Also all these objects are in memory objects, no DB evolved in this part of the process. these are very large collections in memory not sorted.